# Showing that some differential equation has an infinite dimensional solution space?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, vector-spaces

I don't see how to proceed or even where to start to show this thing that I have found:

The differential equation $$(\sin x)\frac{dy}{dx} - 2(\cos x)y = 0$$ has an infinite solution space of functions defined on the whole real line.

I personally see $y = A \sin^2 x$ where $A$ is any real constant, but doesn't this give only one dimension? I've thought about using periodicity but that's not convincing!

Can anyone help me with some hints?

Thanks a lot, I'm really nowhere in the proof.

Comment: What makes you think the solution space is infinite-dimensional?  It certainly is infinite, in the sense that it contains infinitely many solutions.  But it's a linear first-order equation, so its solution space is one-dimensional.

Comment: @JackLee note that the equation degenerates in $x=\pi k$, $k\in \Bbb Z$, so the usual Cauchy-Lipschitz theory doesn't work.

Comment: It's an old examination paper... I thought it could be a misprint or a mistake in the expression but it seems to really mean infinite-dimensional...

Comment: @TZakrevsky -- I completely missed that.  Nice.

Answer (score 1):

In your case for $x=\pi k$ the differential equation degenerates; for the Cauchy problem
$$\begin{cases} \sin x \frac{dy(x)}{dx}=2\cos x y(x)\\y(0)=0 \end{cases}$$
you have a solution $y(x)=0$ and $y(x)=A \sin^2 x$. Note also that these solutions have $y(\pi k)=0$ and $y'(\pi k)=0$ for integer $k$.

Therefore, you can define a familiy of functions for $k\in\Bbb Z$
$$g_k(x) = \begin{cases}\sin^2 x,&x\in [\pi k,\pi(k+1)]\\0,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Finally, let $\{c_k\}_{k\in\Bbb Z}$ be a family of constants. We write a function
$$G_c(x)=\sum_{k\in \Bbb Z}c_k g_k(x).$$ It's easy to show that this function is $C^1(\Bbb R)$.

This function solves the Cauchy problem I wrote above, and the space of such solutions is of infinite dimension (at least, we showed that there's an at least countable set of linearly independent vectors - functions $g_k$).